# Correr un jar ejecutable Java en una PC

Tags: java

Una pregunta para sacarme de las dudas, tengo un jar ejecutable que corre sin problema en mi PC. Para hacerlo correr en otra PC, necesito saber que instalarle. Siguiendo con el tema, las librerías propias de java se genera todas en el jar, es así. Desde ya gracias y saludos.

Comment: Por favor [edit] tu pregunta sobre las característica de tu PC: `sistema operativo, etc`; también depende de tu aplicación: ¿qué tan compleja es o qué requiere ara funcionar en otro equipo, posiblemente con otro sistema operativo?...en mi opinión, tu pregunta se basa principalmente en opiniones. Aún no he votado para cerrar, pero, si editas tu pregunta y la mejoras según la guía ¿cómo elaborar una buena pregunta?, creo que podrías tener algunas respuestas que te ayuden.

Answer (score 1):

para que puedas correr una aplicación en otro equipo, necesitas tener instalado JRE(Java RunTime Enviroment).

Tambien puedes presionar el boton derecho del mouse, manten pulsado la tecla SHIFT y te saldrá un menu desplegable del jar, selecciona "ABRIR CON:" selecionas JAVA(TM)Plataform SE Binary

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre8-downloads-2133155.html

Answer (score 0):

Primero debes posicionarte en la carpeta que contiene el .jar y escribes el siguiente comando desde cmd :

```
java -jar tuArchivoJar
```

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Configura tus variables de [entorno](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html), luego ejecuta en una consola o terminal:

```
$java -jar archivo.jar
```